# How to Avoid URL parameter inline=1 from visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, url

I have a visualforcepage which is included in a layoutpage.
Viewlayout of this object has an override with another visual force page.

When I  call a pagereference methode from "inline" visualforcepage an try to leave the Iframe and load current objectpage again, salesforce creates a new URL with parameter inline=1.
By this parameter, Header and Sidebar is invisible.

Vf page:

```
<apex:commandLink value="edit" action="{!Edit}" id="cl" target="_blank">
</apex:commandlink>
```

Is there a possibility to avoid getting parameter inline=1?

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess:

If you can override this param by your controller method then it would work:

```
PageReference ref = MyPage.page
ref.getParemeters().put('inline','0');
// or try
//ref.getParemeters().remove('inline');
return ref
```

If there is standard controller then you can do like this:

```
<apex:commandLink value="edit" action="{!Edit}" id="cl" target="_blank">
    <apex:param name="inline" value="0"/>
</apex:commandlink>
```

Comment: Just for a reference this does not work - you get ?inline=0&inline=1

Comment: This solution should be removed since it does not work.